# Provide a default image for image field programmatically at theme level

Tags: nodes, theming

I have an image field on a node, which will not always be populated. In the case where the field is empty (no image), I want to alter the markup to display a random image which always exists in a specified directory of the files dir. The second part isn't a problem, but I am struggling with the alter part. I am trying to find the correct hook or theme function to test if the image field is empty and then render some markup in it's place. I am lead towards a theme function. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7). Check over there that if images is empty then fetch image from your whatever custom directory and print it. For printing an image use [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

Comment: Hi Deepak, hook_node_view_alter provides a render array to alter, how will this hook help if I need to 'print' the image using theme_image? Thanks

Comment: hey @davewilly If you got the array, into that you will get the image. check there if any image is there or not, then do your logic.

Comment: Yes but I will then need to provide a full render array for the image. I just want to provide the markup at a theme level.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by providing a default image for the field, and then using theme_preprocess_field to alter the uri. I'm not currently sure what adverse effects this may have.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_myfield_image') {
    $variables['items'][0]['#item']['uri'] = 'public://path_to_img/my_new_image.jpg';
  }
}
```